# Como puedo hacer que cin lea de un literal de cadena en vez de la entrada estándar

Tags: c++

Contexto:
Estaba viendo la sección 3.1.6 del libro "el lenguaje de programación c++" (por bjarne stroustrup, 2da edición), básicamente en el capítulo venía haciendo una calculadora de escritorio. En un momento se plantea que es molesto tener que iniciar por primera vez el programa, después poner la expresión a evaluar, y por último salir. Siendo que su utilización más común es la evaluación de una sola expresión.

Siendo que todo el código escrito hasta el momento estaba usando cin la idea era (sin cambiar nada) poder agregar que el usuario directo pueda meter la expresión cómo argumento.
De ahí sale esta parte del código:

```
switch (argc)
    {
        case 1:
            break; //sigue como si nada hubiera pasado
        case 2:
            std::cin = *new std::istrstream(argv[1],std::strlen(argv[1]));//esto da error
            break;
        default:
            error("Demasiados argumentos");
            return 1;
    }
```

Que en definitiva la parte que me interesa es:

```
std::cin = *new std::istrstream(argv[1],std::strlen(argv[1]));
```

Que lo que está haciendo es que cin en vez de leer de la entrada estándar lea de un literal de cadena, particularmente en este caso de uno de los argumentos de la línea de comandos.
Ahora bien, cuando lo voy a ejecutar me tira un error:

```
g++ -Wall -o "ce" "ce.cpp" (en el directorio: C:\Users\confidencial\Documents\Programas C++\Calculadora de escritorio)
ce.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
ce.cpp:186:41: error: expected type-specifier
  186 |                         std::cin = *new std::istrstream(argv[1],std::strlen(argv[1])); //parece que esto da error, se ve que tiene su contraparte moderna en std::istringstream pero no sé como se usa
      |                                         ^~~
Ha fallado la compilación.
```

Quería saber como puedo solucionar dicho error. Cuando averigüe acerca del tema parece que istrstream esta obsoleto desde 1998, y que su reemplazo es std::istringstream, pero no entendí como se usa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactamente para el estandar `c++98` fue donde se añadió `istringstream`. Esta es una clase de la biblioteca estándar de C++ (biblioteca `<sstream>`). Se utiliza para realizar la lectura de datos desde una cadena (string) como si estuviera leyendo desde un flujo de entrada (stream).

Su uso es bastante sencillo, solo se necesita pasar un string que será convertido en un stream para ser leído. Aquí un ejemplo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string data = "10 20 30 40 50";
  std::istringstream iss(data);

  int number;
  while (iss >> number) {
    std::cout << number << " ";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

En tu caso, el reemplazo es bastante sencillo. Por lo que veo tratas de guardar en un buffer el argumento ingresado por el usuario y redirigir la entrada a `std::cin`.

Primero se crea un objeto `istringstream` basado en el segundo argumento pasado al programa, luego se redirige el flujo de entrada para que se lea desde el bufer del objeto, esto mediante el método `rdbuf` de `std::cin`.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    switch (argc)
    {
        case 2:{
            std::istringstream iss(argv[1]); // se crea el objeto
            std::cin.rdbuf(iss.rdbuf()); // se lee desde el  buffer de iss
            break;
        }
        default:
            std::cout << "Demasiados argumentos";
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Si quieres puedes leer más en estos links:

- [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/processing-strings-using-stdistringstream/)
- [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream)